# Performance issues in postgres

Tags: postgresql, performance

I'm trying to improve performance in postgres and in my top for slow queries I have:

```
postgres=>  select
postgres->   query,
postgres->   calls,
postgres->   total_time::BIGINT,
postgres->   (calls/total_time)::integer as ms_per_call,
postgres->   shared_blks_hit,
postgres->   shared_blks_read
postgres->  from pg_stat_statements pss
postgres->  order by ms_per_call desc
postgres->  limit 10;
                                                              query                                                               |   calls   | total_time | ms_per_call | shared_blks_hit | shared_blks_read
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+------------+-------------+-----------------+------------------
 COMMIT                                                                                                                           | 548086670 |     546821 |        1002 |               0 |                0
 BEGIN                                                                                                                            | 195900624 |     252227 |         777 |               0 |                0
 ROLLBACK                                                                                                                         |   5478093 |       7857 |         697 |               0 |                0
 select * from company_reason c where company_id = $1 and id = $2 for update                                                      |    192822 |        531 |         363 |           11334 |               16
```

What'd be the reason for COMMIT, BEGIN and ROLLBACK being in the top 3? Could it be a bad config on the app side?

If I do:

```
postgres=>  select
  query,
  calls,
  total_time::BIGINT,
  (total_time/calls)::integer as ms_per_call,
  shared_blks_hit,
  shared_blks_read
 from pg_stat_statements pss
 order by ms_per_call desc
 limit 10;
  COPY user_name.company_employee_employment_archive (company_id, employee_id, employment_id, position_id, location_id, start_date, end_date, primary_employment, system_generated, wage, reason_id, comment, deactivator_id) TO stdout                                             |  1271 |   63866602 |       50249 |       355947227 |          6591
 176
  COPY user_name.company_employee_target_audience (company_id, employee_id, target_audience_id, target_audience_company_id, update_timestamp) TO stdout                                                                                                                             |  1271 |    9269684 |        7293 |        47827900 |           155
 888
  COPY user_name.company_employee_employment (company_id, employee_id, employment_id, position_id, location_id, start_date, end_date, primary_employment, system_generated, wage) TO stdout                                                                                         |  1271 |    3675987 |        2892 |        29494109 |            38
 241
  COPY user_name.resource (id, first_name, last_name, birth_date, locale, phone_list, email, username, avatar_url) TO stdout                                                                                                                                                        |  1271 |    1886975 |        1485 |         8902906 |            10
 127
  UPDATE "company_location" SET "name_map"=to_json($1::json),"external_id"=$2,"external_code"=$3,"type"=$4,"time_zone_id"=$5,"address"=to_json($6::json),"groups"=to_json($7::json),"classifications"=to_json($8::json),"logical_delete"=$9,"update_timestamp"=$10 WHERE (company_id = $11 AND id = $12) | 75125 |  111219834 |        1480 |     12835084480 |        110844
 167
  COPY user_name.elastic_search_indexing_request (company_id, employee_id, event_generated, update_timestamp) TO stdout                                                                                                                                                             |  1271 |    1569711 |        1235 |        10525136 |            17
 397
  COPY user_name.company_employee (company_id, employee_id, resource_id, external_id, external_code, punch_badge_id, worker_type, minor, seniority_date, status, update_timestamp) TO stdout                                                                                        |  1271 |    1214460 |         956 |         9779303 |
   0
  COPY user_name.company_location (id, company_id, name_map, external_id, external_code, type, time_zone_id, logical_delete, update_timestamp, address, groups, classifications) TO stdout                                                                                          |  1271 |    1160202 |         913 |         7356054 |             5
 917
  COPY user_name.resource_notification_setting (id, locale, notification_push, notification_email, notification_sms, minutes_before_shift_reminder, update_timestamp) TO stdout                                                                                                     |  1271 |     557911 |         439 |         7318193 |            27
 526
  COPY user_name.company_employee_badge (company_id, employee_id, badge_id, badge_level, update_timestamp) TO stdout                                                                                                                                                                |  1271 |     473524 |         373 |         3601710 |            13
 788
 (10 rows)

 postgres=>
```

So probably I'll need to break it into small batches.

Thank you.

Comment: I suggest you might want to do ```(total_time/calls)::integer``` but not 
```(calls/total_time)::integer```

Comment: Your application is creating many transactions, using BEGIN, COMMIT and ROLLBACK. I would be especially worried about the rollback's, why do they happen?

Comment: @BjarniRagnarsson I add the result on the post.

Comment: @FrankHeikens they're done on the app side and unfartunally I do not have access to them. I'll get the dev team involved on it to see what is going on.

Comment: If you sort a list, something will always come out on the top.  This does not indicate a problem.  Are your users complaining? If so, what are they complaining about?

Comment: You should display ms_per_call.  It might be zero in most cases as calls/total_time is likely to be below 1 and the integer conversion truncates it to zero.  I suggest you skip the conversion alltogether.

Comment: @jjanes Thanks for replaying. They are complaining about it has being using a lot of hardware for a small DB. it's using a 24cpus and 24GB RAM for 500 millionsish rows. But I think it's lated to the COPY operations that are being performed.

Comment: So it isn't the end users complaining about the performance they experience, but the IT accountants complaining about the cost?  Those copy operations are probably driven by pg_dump (i.e. your backups, I would guess).  But you should probably really be looking at the total time (or blocks read, or something), not the average time.